# Constructor error while sceduling AlarmManager and worker in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, android-jetpack-compose, worker

I'm currently working on a habit tracking app and I'm trying to implement a feature that resets the checked state of habits at midnight using WorkManager. However, I've encountered an issue where the worker is giving this error.

```
Could not instantiate com.shahzaman.habitslog.habitFeature.data.worker.ResetHabitsWorker
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.shahzaman.habitslog.habitFeature.data.worker.ResetHabitsWorker.<init> [class android.content.Context, class androidx.work.WorkerParameters]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2332)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2170)
    at androidx.work.WorkerFactory.createWorkerWithDefaultFallback(WorkerFactory.java:95)
    at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.runWorker(WorkerWrapper.java:243)
    at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.run(WorkerWrapper.java:145)
    at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutorImpl$Task.run(SerialExecutorImpl.java:96)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
WM-WorkerWrapper E  Could not create Worker com.shahzaman.habitslog.habitFeature.data.worker.ResetHabitsWorker
```

This is my worker.

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.work.CoroutineWorker
import androidx.work.WorkerParameters
import com.shahzaman.habitslog.habitFeature.domain.repository.HabitRepository
import dagger.assisted.Assisted
import dagger.assisted.AssistedInject
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.map
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext

class ResetHabitsWorker @AssistedInject constructor(
    private val context: Context,
    private val workerParams: WorkerParameters,
    @Assisted private val repository: HabitRepository
) : CoroutineWorker(context, workerParams) {

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        return try {
            performResetHabits()
            Result.success()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Result.failure()
        }
    }

    private suspend fun performResetHabits() {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val habits = repository.getAllHabits() // get all habits
            habits.map { habits ->
                habits.forEach { habit ->
                    val updatedHabit = habit.copy(isChecked = false)
                    repository.upsertHabit(updatedHabit)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my BroadcastReciever.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.work.Constraints
import androidx.work.OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder
import androidx.work.WorkManager
import com.shahzaman.habitslog.habitFeature.data.worker.ResetHabitsWorker

class DailyWorkerReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val resetRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<ResetHabitsWorker>()
            .setConstraints(Constraints.Builder().build())
            .build()

        WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(resetRequest)
    }
}
```

And here I implemented it.

```
private fun scheduleDailyWorker() {
    val alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    val intent = Intent(this, DailyWorkerReceiver::class.java)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0)

    val currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val midnightMillis = LocalDate.now().plusDays(1).atStartOfDay().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli()
    val timeUntilMidnightMillis = midnightMillis - currentTimeMillis

    alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(
        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        currentTimeMillis + timeUntilMidnightMillis,
        pendingIntent
    )
}
```

I think the missing part is injecting context and worker parameters into the worker, I have no idea how to do that, so your help will be beneficial.

Comment: I am also facing same problem suddenly. It worked fine before, but after upgrading gradle and some other libraries, this problem arised.